# Diagram not possible under R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Good morning all ,

I have a problem with my dataset. Indeed I would like to have the number of the question on the abscissa and the corresponding number of correct answers on the ordinate.

But under R with GGPLOT2 I cannot get the histogram in this direction.

I managed to do it with a code under GGPLOT2, but it gives me the question numbers in absicsse a bit in the mess and not in the order of the table.

Here is my data table

| N ° | GOOD | BAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 62 | 37 |
| 2 | 95 | 4 |
| 3 | 36 | 63 |
| 4 | 82 | 17 |

```
Histo_1 =    ggplot(BONNE_MAUVAISE_1) +   
  aes(x = NUMERO, weight = BONNE) +   
  geom_bar(fill = "#0c4c8a") +   
  theme_minimal()+
  labs(title = "Diagramme en barres représentant le taux de bonnes réponse par questions",      
       x = "Numero des questions", 
       y = "Taux de bonnes réponses")+   
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "greenyellow"),      
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "greenyellow"))
```

Thanks for help.

Good Day

Comment: Can you show the attempts with code?

Comment: `Histo_1 = 
  ggplot(BONNE_MAUVAISE_1) +
  aes(x = NUMERO, weight = BONNE) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#0c4c8a") +
  theme_minimal()+labs(title = "Diagramme en barres représentant le taux de bonnes réponse par questions", 
    x = "Numero des questions", y = "Taux de bonnes réponses")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "greenyellow"), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "greenyellow"))

Histo_1`

Comment: It seems you want `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar()` if you got pre-counted data.

Comment: So I would have to replace the geom_bar by geom_col?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm suggesting to try.

Comment: Thanks for your help it works. I was not aware of the geom_col function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they key is to `pivot_longer` so that you can map an aesthetic to the type of response ("GOOD", "BAD").

```r
# load packages
library(tidyverse)

# set up data
BONNE_MAUVAISE_1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "N GOOD    BAD
1   62  37
2   95  4
3   36  63
4   82  17") 

# pivot long to plot
BONNE_MAUVAISE_2 <- BONNE_MAUVAISE_1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-N, names_to = "type")

# plot data
ggplot(BONNE_MAUVAISE_2, aes(x = N, y = value)) +   
  geom_col(aes(alpha = type), position = "dodge", fill = "#0c4c8a") +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.6, 0.9)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Diagramme en barres représentant le taux de bonnes réponse par questions",      
       x = "Numero des questions", 
       y = "Taux de bonnes réponses") +   
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "greenyellow"),      
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "greenyellow"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer also I will use the two functions to have two different visuals

Comment: Ok, if you still don't get what you need feel free to revise your question to clarify and we can update the answer.